# How do I remove 'Earth' button from Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-earth

I'm using the Google Maps generator to create a few maps for a client. The maps embeded on the site are a bit small (255x176), so map real state is crucial. I've already removed the balloon, but can't find a way to remove the "Earth" view button from it (all newly generated maps come with it now, 4 views in total).

The annoying part is that the "Earth" view requires a Google Earth plugin to be used anyway, something the client could live without - me too.

Any advices there? Feedback will be greatly appreciated!

Cheers,
Wallace

Answer (score 0):

You may customize the map controls using the MAPS API.

Visit http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/controls.html#DefaultUI

Look for MapTypeControlOptions and pass appropriate map type you want to show.

Refer http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MapTypeControlOptions

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MapTypeId

Comment: So you are saying I have to override the map with some more Javascript in the bottom of the document (or right below the map I want to edit) and somehow rebuild it? Like "disable the default UI" - stripping the whole thing down - and then pick the variables I need?

Answer (score 0):

If using the default UI, you would get only the map types in G_DEFAULT_MAP_TYPES, which does not include the Earth map type (G_SATELLITE_3D_MAP).

This means your generator is adding this map type explicitly.  So you should be able to simply look for G_SATELLITE_3D_MAP in the javascript you get from the generator, and remove references to it.

If you are still having troubles, can you provide a link to the map generator you are using?